# Text out of button border

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm practicing `bootstrap` buttons. 
I've written the following code

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-success performanceButton">Best case performance</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-warning performanceButton">Average case performance </button>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
</div>
```

The code is working well, but when I test it for small screen size by downsizing the browser it seems that the text in the second button expands out of the button.

Here is a screen capture of the issue.

[image: Text expanding out of button using bootstrap]

Does anyone know how to solve this please ? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your columns bigger for smaller screens, try this:

```
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-success performanceButton">Best case performance</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6">  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-warning performanceButton">Average case performance </button>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was so useful and practical for even future situations.

Comment: After practicing, I understand that we need to manage almost all screen sizes. I thought we need to manage only one :D

Answer (score 1):

By giving `min-width` property to your button, it won't break.

```css
button {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <button class="btn btn-success performanceButton">Best case performance</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <button class="btn btn-warning performanceButton">Average case performance </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also make the text of button wrap instead of making button larger
just jive button a class like  and in css

```
    .wrapit{
             width: 30px;
             white-space: normal;
             word-Wrap: break-word;
            }
```